# How to call Amazon API Gateway in LibGDX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, libgdx, aws-api-gateway

I'm developing a game for iOS and Android using LibGDX. I would like to use Amazon Web Services and I haven't found if there is a library or a way to access API Gateway from my (:core) project.

I've worked with API Gateway in Android and iOS native projects and is very easy to implement it because Amazon has SDK Generation for both platforms. But since there's not a way to export for Java, it seems to bee a little tricky to make api calls from the core project.

I tried to use amazon skd for android inside (:core) but it didn't worked.

May be making a direct Http request using HttpURLConnection, but I don't know how to do it and although it won't map the response objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have specific experience with LibGDX, but API Gateway helps you generate REST based APIs. There are a number of Java libraries that will help you interact with REST based APIs, such as [rest4j](http://www.rest4j.com/). As you note, you will have to either forgo using API Gateway's Models or build your own marshalling code on top whatever solution you use for interacting with your API.